# Union usage and messy code

Tags: c++, gcc, unions

I have some code which is about the usage of union shown as following:

```
int main(){

  typedef union{int a;char b[10];float c;}Union;

  Union x,y = {100};
  printf("Union x :%d|   |%s|   |%f \n",x.a,x.b,x.c );
  printf("Union y :%d|   |%s|   |%f \n\n",y.a,y.b,y.c);

  x.a = 50;
  printf("Union x :%d|   |%s|   |%f \n",x.a,x.b,x.c );
  printf("Union y :%d|   |%s|   |%f \n\n",y.a,y.b,y.c);

  strcpy(x.b,"hello");
  printf("Union x :%d|   |%s|   |%f \n",x.a,x.b,x.c );
  printf("Union y :%d|   |%s|   |%f \n\n",y.a,y.b,y.c);

  x.c = 21.50;
  printf("Union x :%d|   |%s|   |%f \n",x.a,x.b,x.c );
  printf("Union y :%d|   |%s|   |%f \n\n",y.a,y.b,y.c);

  return 0;
}
```

After I compile and execute above code, I had result like this:

```
  Union x :0|     ||    |0.000000 
  Union y :100|   |d|   |0.000000 

  Union x :50|    |2|   |0.000000 
  Union y :100|   |d|   |0.000000 

  Union x :1819043176|     |hello|      |1143141483620823940762435584.000000 
  Union y :100|   |d|   |0.000000 

  Union x :1101791232|   ||    |21.500000 
  Union y :100|   |d|   |0.000000
```

I do not know why the y.b is initialized as "d"? and why x.a and x.c's value changed after? why does the strcpy(x.b,"hello") not work?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I'm using g++.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I'm newbie for c++ :) How to quote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly by the standard *type-punning* expect in narrow circumstances is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) but in practice many compilers support it for example [gcc manual points here for type-punning](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type-punning) and under *-fstrict-aliasing* section is says:

> The practice of reading from a different union member than the one most recently written to (called “type-punning”) is common. Even with -fstrict-aliasing, type-punning is allowed, provided the memory is accessed through the union type.

I would recommend reading [Understanding Strict Aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) if you plan on using *type-punning* a lot.

`y.b` has the value `b` since all the elements of the union share memory and you initialized `y` with `100` which in *ASCII* is `b`. This is the same reason why the other fields of `x` change when you modify one including the case of `strcpy` and depending on your compiler this may be undefined or well defined(*in the case of gcc it is defined*).

For completeness sake the C++ draft standard section `9.5` *Unions* paragraph *1* says(*emphasis mine*):

> In a union, **at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time**, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time. [ Note: One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence (9.2), and **if an object of this standard-layout union type contains one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of standard-layout struct members**; see 9.2. —end note ] The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its non-static data members. Each non-static data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a struct.

Answer (score 2):

If you see an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you will see that the value `100` is the same as the character `'d'`.

You have to remember that all members of a union *shares* the same memory. This means that if you set one member of a union, *all* members change, and not always to something comprehensible. Therefore it's undefined behavior to write to one member and read from another.

And `strcpy(x.b,"hello")` does indeed work, as you can see all the members of the`x` union change after you do that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has UB (undefined behaviour); it is illegal to assign to one member of a union and then inspect a different member (except for a special case of POD structs with the same initial members).

It is also illegal to read an uninitialised value, such as any field of `x` before you assign into `x.a`.

Comment: It should be noted that `Union x,y = {100};` initializes only `y`, `x` remains uninitialized. You should use `Union x = {100}, y = {100};` or, better yet, `Union x = {100};` and `Union y = {100};`

Answer (score -2):

I think when you say int a , you allocate sizeof(int) , generally 32 bits.
but when you say char[10] , you are allocating 10 * sizeof(char) bytes !! (10 * 4 bits)
these two can not be casted to each other.

Comment: AFAIK , in unions , data parts should be same size , or i am making a mistake ???

Comment: In union, all type shares the same memory, where the biggest determines its length. In this case, considering a 32 bit machine, with 4 byte of alignment, probably, it size is 12 bytes, 10 for char (the biggest) e 2 for alignments, and as Angew said, you dont need to use cast to access any member of it.